# why asyncio tasks not working as expected?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi

I am building an API with fastapi using asyncio.

I have several problems regarding asyncio task that I could not find anything about how to solve them.

1. I have several tasks I want to perform on the background and regularly (sending pings to 3rd party servers, waiting to read/write from WS, etc..) and I use the lifespan hook to create them with asyncio.create_task:

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    from .session import session
    from .sm import state_manager
    from .ws import ws_manager

    session_periodoc_ping_task = asyncio.create_task(session.periodoc_ping(60))
    ws_manager_task = asyncio.create_task(ws_manager.run())
    
    state_manager_save_state_task = asyncio.create_task(state_manager.try_restore_state())

    
    yield

    ws_manager_task.do_graceful_shutdown()
    state_manager.do_graceful_shutdown()
    session.do_graceful_shutdown()
    print("Did graceful shutdown")
```

now for some reason `ws_manager_task` and `state_manager_save_state_task` dont want to work together, as if one is blocking the other

2. I have another task I wanted to create, this time inside an endpoint function:

```
@router.post("/update")
async def update(new_val, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    logger.debug({'event': 'endpoint_called',
                  'endpoint': '/update',
                  })

    background_tasks.add_task(start_update, new_val)

    return {
        'result': 'success'
    }
```

and `start_update` looks like so:

```
async def start_update(new_val):
    # a function with lots of "await"s for other corotines
    a = await some_coro_1(new_val)
    b = await some_coro_2(a)
    ....
    z = await some_coro_2(y)
    return z
```

for some reason, FastAPI waits for my update corotine to finish and only then he returns the `{'result': 'success'}`. I have no idea why this happening and I've spent days trying to figure this out without any help (the docs specifically says it is supposed to start working on the task only after the response is sent).

Will appreciate any help about how to fix this or what to read in order to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that something inside `some_coro_...` is making sync requests? While it may not be the case for why something runs before the return happens, it might be that the tasks gets started before the response has been displayed to the user, and then locks up the event loop? You could try to just define the function as `def` instead of async to have it run in a threadpool instead.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) answer your question?